# Error: EADDRINUSE connect EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:50596 when running e2e test suit on VS code

Tags: protractor, vscode-extensions

When I run e2e test suites on VS code getting an unusual error - **Error: EADDRINUSE connect EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:50596** don't know how to solve this, its happening to all instance and failing all test cases with same error. when I debug this in dev tools getting this error in console log (**node:16612) [DEP0005] Deprecation Warning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the buffer. From() methods instead.
(Use `Code --trace-deprecation …` to show where the warning was created)**

Node version >v11.15.0**
NPM. version >6.7.0
Chrome browser

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error `Error: EADDRINUSE connect EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:50596` means the address `127.0.0.1:50596` is already used.

You can find out what's using the port 50596, and then kill the process (see https://www.printsupportcenter.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003386949-Determine-which-program-uses-or-blocks-a-port):

Windows:
`netstat -ano -p tcp | find "50596"`

Linux/Mac:
`sudo netstat -ano -p tcp | grep ":50596"`

These previous commands will give you the Process IDentifier (PID), which you can then use to kill your process:

Windows:
`taskkill /PID <pid_number>`

Linux/Mac:
`kill <pid_number>`